# For EditText, how do I let the keyboard not cover it and some other views?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

### Background

I have an EditText, that when focusing on it, it should show a keyboard and yet show the entire EditText and I might need to include few Views below.

### The problem

Due to some requirements, I need the EditText to be of some small text size yet have a minimal height too.

I've made a snippet to make a tiny example of the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="write here" android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" tools:background="" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I focus on the EditText, for some reason I don't see its line:

[image]

In the manifest, I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` because the requirement is to move things and not resize them.

### What I've tried

I tried to add padding, and I tried to add a fake bottom drawable. Those can only add empty space, but will make the line even further from being shown.

### The question

Is it possible to have the EditText have this minimal height and textsize, while also letting it line being shown when the keyboard appears?

Is it also possible to even show a bit more below the EditText ? It's not so nice to have the EditText be so near the keyboard. I know that in this snippet I only have the EditText, but imagine I would have more views below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way.  THere are only 3 ways of reacting when the keyboard opens:

1)Do nothing
2)Resize
3)Pan, such that the line with the cursor is on screen.

There is no way to do anything else, and no reliable signal sent to the app that the keyboard is showing you can respond to.  There especially is no way to ensure the line at the bottom of an EditText is going to be on screen.

The best you can do to try to ensure that is to resize, and carefully layout your content so that the resize has minimal effect on the ui shown.  But that may or may not be possible, depending on the specifics of the UI.  And you haven't shown us enough of what you're trying to do to give you suggestions on it.

Comment: What more information do you want?Sample has just EditText...

Comment: If its literally just a screen with an edit text at the bottom, use adjustResize.  Its when you put content above the edit text that you may not get the results you hope for.

Comment: Using adjustResize doesn't help, and the requirement makes it not a possible option anyway. And I can put content below. Not above. It's just that the Keyboard appears way too close to the EditText, which is why I made this tiny sample (to demonstrate the exact same issue on the real case).

Comment: @androiddeveloper WHat you want isn't possible.  You can use resize, or you have to live with this.  Those are your options.

Comment: Maybe, but don't you consider this a bug that the EditText can sometimes hide its line just because it's focused, instead of changing its color?

Comment: @androiddeveloper No.  The behavior is documented that pan will only move the screen so that the cursor is visible.  It does not say, and in the 10 years Android has been out has never moved the screen to keep the full edit text in view.  That's the intended behavior.  The only way to get what you want to happen is to use resize mode, and write the content of your entire screen such that the area above the edit text shrinks if the screen is restricted in size.

Comment: So that's impossible. I've seen "resize" mode actually worse in terms of UX (check Contacts app of Google when editing a contact, where the keyboard sometimes hides the EditText right away)... I don't understand your last sentence though. Have you tried it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper My problem is exactly same with you. There is no way to have some space between keyboard and editText right?

Comment: @AhmetYılmaz I don't remember. It was a very long time ago. Perhaps we left this idea. Perhaps we had some weird workaround....

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code in AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

This code worked for me.
Inside the manifest file in activity tag add this attribute:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

Comment: It doesn't help. Plus I'm required to move things, and not to resize them

Answer (score 0):

you can in the android manifest set `windowSoftInputMode`.

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                       "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] > 
</activity>
```

In your condition, I think you should use `adjustPan`. your window size it not change, but the content translates up.  the following is the document says about `adjustPan` :

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

if you don't want the content view layout translate, which makes the content scroll out screen. you can use `adjustResize`

if you want to know more, you can read the official [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I already have adjustPan being set. It doesn't help. I want it to translate, but just have some space (and even views) still being shown below the EditText. Currently it can even hide the line of the EditText, which is really bad. I've updated the question.

Comment: for that complex situation, I think you can try to custom your own keyboard